# Asp.net MVC Razor - Custom javascript inside if block

Tags: javascript, parsing, razor, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I put javascript code inside if block.

```
@{
    #if DEBUG
    $("#User").val("JDoe");
    $("#Password").val("secrect");
    #endif
}
```

When I try above code I get this compiler error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1056: Unexpected character '$'
```

And if I change $ to jQuery:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'jQuery' does not exist in the current context
```

In my opinion it's a bug in Razor parser. How can I workaround that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@{#if DEBUG}
    $("#User").val("JDoe");
    $("#Password").val("secrect");
@{#endif}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the javascript code within  tag.

```
@{(if DEBUG)
    **<text>**
    $("#User").val("JDoe");
    $("#Password").val("secrect");
   **</text>**
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer, since <text> pseudo tag works in more cases.Eg., it could work with for loops too.